MariaDB, Mysql, Mysql Workbench and multiple users
We have a new Dell computer and want to work with mysql databases on it. In the past, we used Mysql workbench, Mysql-server and unique users on each computer, but now we want to give access to multiple users.
However, on our new computer, Fedora 40 Scientific is installed as operating system and this includes MariaDB instead of MysqlDB. How can we configure our computer and software such that more than one user can work with mysql databases on it?

You can install MySQL on any Linux. Yum packages are available if you add MySQL's Yum repo. Instructions are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

MySQL can coexist on a server with MariaDB, provided you configure them with distinct ports, sockets, and datadirs. Alternatively, you can uninstall MariaDB.

Then it's just a matter of adding users that permit remote connections. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/creating-accounts.html

I’m not sure whether you realize this: MariaDb and MySql are almost entirely compatible with each other. Various Linux distros use the MariaDb fork because it’s getting more love from its developers than MySql is from its Oracle overlords.

@O.Jones that was true 14 years ago, when the two forked. By now the list of incompatibilities is pretty long and discrepancies started to appear even on protocol level.

This question should really have been asked on the DBA sister-site of SO as it is not about programming, but installing and configuring mysql.

@Shadow fair enough, you are right.  My work is with the WordPress application for MariaDB  / MySQL where the two are indeed used interchangeably, so that's the way I think about it.  Measured by number of server instances, that has to be the biggest application of that strain of DBMS.

Core wordpress is probably designed to work with both database products. That's not impossible. But when you use mysql workbench, then there is no application to hide that complexity. Workbench sends the queries as you typed them.

Make sure the MariaDB server is started up by running systemctl start mariadb.service. You can then access the MariaDB instance on the local server as the root user using sudo mariadb. If you need remote access, make sure you set bind-address=0.0.0.0 in a configuration file (usually in /etc/my.cnf.d/ for Fedora).
For each user who you want to give access to, create a new user using the CREATE USER SQL command. This gives them access to the database.
If you want to just isolate users to their own subsets of tables, you can use the CREATE SCHEMA command to create a schema for each user and then grant them permission to do what they want using the GRANT command.
For example, if I have users bob and alice and I want bob to have access to the bob_db schema and alice to have access to the alice_db schema, I'd execute the following SQL:
CREATE USER bob IDENTIFIED BY 'bob_secret';
CREATE SCHEMA bob_db;
GRANT ALL ON bob_db.* TO bob;

CREATE USER alice IDENTIFIED BY 'alice_secret';
CREATE SCHEMA alice_db;
GRANT ALL ON alice_db.* TO alice;


This looks great, but it tells me after the create user statement that MariaDB is running in --skip-grant-tables mode. How can I fix it?


mysql workbench is designed to work with mysql, not with mariadb. They will get lots of errors as workbench will try to do things the mysql way. They would need to migrate database structure and queries as well as there is no guarantee that either will work with mariadb. 2) This question has nothing to do with programming. With any decent database admin GUI, user creation and access rights assignment is just a few clicks on a form.



MariaDB is running in --skip-grant-tables mode. How can I fix it?

Ensure that skip-grant-tables isn't part of the  the configuration files /etc/my.cnf.d/*. SHUTDOWN the instance, and start the systemctl start mariadb.service.
